# Is a similar statement on 10th topic of a purana from Bhagavata found in any other purana?

Tags: identification-request, bhagavata-purana

[Bhagavata 2.10.1-2](http://srimadbhagavatam.org/canto2/chapter10.html) reads:

> (1) S'rî S'uka said: 'In this [book, the S'rîmad Bhâgavatam] the
>   following [ten] subjects are discussed: primary creation [sarga], how
>   the interactions of life and the lifeless came about [visarga], the
>   planetary order [sthâna], the maintenance of belief [poshana], the
>   impetus for action [ûtaya], the administrative eras [manvantaras],
>   stories about the Lord's appearances [îs'a-anukathâ], renouncing a
>   material life [nirodha], liberation in devotional service [mukti] and
>   the shelter [the refuge of Krishna, âs'raya].
>
> (2) Great souls, sages, reasoning from Vedic texts and their purport,
>   state that the purpose of the first nine characteristics of this book
>   is to offer a clear notion of the tenth subject.

Major Puranas deal with 10 topics indicated in the first verse. The second verse says first nine are delineated to explain 10th topic(asraya) clearly.

The question now concerns only the 2nd verse of the above two verses. Is a similar statement found in any other purana?